# In which tables are stored some Sales Order dates

Tags: sap-erp

I want to make an excel graphic with 3 values:

- Sales Order Date (The date sales enters the sales order)
- Requirement Date (The date the customer wants this order)
- Closed Sales Order Date (When sales closes the order)

This will be used to measure the service of our plant against completed delivered sales orders monthly.

I already found the first 2 data cells on table VBMTV, anyone has an idea where can I get the information regarding as the date sales close the order once it has been delivered to the customer?

Regards,

Comment: I imagine this is something you should be able to find by wading through the documentation for SAP.  It may not be readily apparently, though, if you aren't familiar with SAP's architechture, so you may want to ensure your'e solid on how that works first if you aren't.  At least, that's how finding things in Siebel worked.

Comment: Whats your system R/3 or CRM?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the data is displayed in a transaction, you can do the following:

- position the cursor in the field you are interested in
- press F1 - you get a help text in a dialog labeled 'Performance Assistant'
- click the button for 'Technical Information' (looks like a hammer and wrench) - you'll get another dialog
- in this dialog there are fields for 'Table Name' and 'Field Name'

For most transactions, this information maps to the specific tables/columns in the database. There are some exceptions to this rule (mostly for those cases where the data is not directly read from the db), but it is a good start and works for about 80% of the cases.

Answer (score 0):

If F1 and Technical Information (F4) does not work you can also try running a trace using ST05.  (Do this only for one user and make sure to disable the trace once you are done).

I believe Sales Order Complete may be a status.  (TECO or "Technically Complete" if I'm correct).  The table that stores the date a specific status was set is JCDS.  You will have to read it on the OBJNR of the sales order and the internal status number of the status that you care about.